# How to use the GAE Memcache in node.js on flexible environment

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, memcached

How to use the GAE Memcache in node.js on flexible environment. I don't see the memcache api back in the node.js client lib. (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/).

There are some examples from using a Redis Labs Memcache instance but nothing on the GAE onboard instance of memcache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GAE Memcache service [is not available](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#memcache) in the App Engine flexible environment. To cache application data, use [MemoryStore for Redis](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex).